# Sending mail to multiple recipients

Tags: php, contact-form

I have this PHP code for sending emails from a website's contact form:

```
<?php

  if(count($_POST) > 0){

    $userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['userEmail'];
    $userSubject = $_POST['userSubject'];
    $userMessage = $_POST['userMessage'];
    $header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To: $userEmail\r\nFrom: $userEmail <$userEmail>";

    $body = 
    @"Contact sent from website ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']." | Day and time ".date("d/m/Y H:i",time())."<br />
    <hr />
    <p><b>Name:</b></p>
    $userName
    <p>———————————</p>
    <p><b>Subject:</b></p>
    $userSubject
    <p>———————————</p>
    <p><b>Mensagem:</b></p>
    $userMessage
    <hr />
    End of message";

    if(mail("email_recipient_1@mailserver.com", "Mensage sent from website", $body, $header)){
      die("true");  
    } else {
        die("Error sending.");  
      }

  }

?>
```

I need to change it in order to send emails to two recipients:

- "email_recipient_1@mailserver.com"
- "email_recipient_2@mailserver.com"

... don't know how, though. Where do I put the other e-mail? I tried adding **"email_recipient_2@mailserver.com"** in the *mail()* but it didn't work...

Thanx.

Pedro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put multiple email addresses into the `to` field by simply adding a comma between them inside the parameter string like this:

```
mail("email1@mailserver.com, email2@mailserver.com", // rest of your code
```

Edit: Per comments below.

you can hide the multiple email addresses by using the additional headers param in the `mail()` function as [per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on it:

```
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

This is the fourth param in the `mail()` arguments passed:

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Comment: If you are doing it this way it will show all email addresses to everyone where this mail has been sent.

Comment: @Andy Yes, but the OP hasn't asked to keep them hidden in any way? Sure, he could use a BCC so that they only see the email as coming to them - but if that was the purpose, surely that would have been mentioned? It might be handy for the OP to be able to use a Reply-All to get it back to whoever got included in the message to start off with? Not saying your comment isn't valid, just sayin'...

Comment: Well, I have **.serialize()** in my jQuery: **$("#userName, #userEmail, #userSubject, #userMessage").serialize();** - that's the way to do it... right?

Comment: @Pedro Have a look at the edit and perhaps take a read of the link that I offered to the docs as well - it goes into much more detail than I gave here :)

Answer (score 2):

From

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
The formatting of this string must comply with » RFC 2822. Some examples are:

user@example.com
user@example.com, anotheruser@example.com
User <user@example.com>
User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put your emails into an array like this example:

```
$recepients = array('recepient1@example.com','recepient2@example.com');

foreach($recepients as $recepient){
    mail($recepient, "Mensage sent from website", $body, $header);
}
```